# Can't access variables outside loop fetching mysql data in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, variables, scope

I am currently trying to access variables outside of a loop which fetches 2 columns of a MySQL table in Bash:

```
mysql dbnameplaceholder -N -uusernameplaceholder -ppasswordplaceholder -
h127.0.0.1 -se "SELECT value1,value2 FROM table1 WHERE 
value1='placeholdervalue'" | while read -r value1 value2;
do
    var_value1="$value1"
    var_value2="$value2"
done
echo "$var_value1  $var_value2" >> /tmp/script_debug
```

but the output is empty.

I did read up on the scope of variables here http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 and changed my original code to the following:

```
var_value1="NULL"
var_value1="NULL"
while read -r value1 value2;
do
    var_value1="$value1"
    var_value2="$value2"
done < <(mysql dbnameplaceholder -N -uusernameplaceholder -ppasswordplaceholder -
h127.0.0.1 -se "SELECT value1,value2 FROM table1 WHERE 
value1='placeholdervalue'")
echo "$var_value1  $var_value2" >> /tmp/script_debug
```

but that did not work either.

By the way if i echo inside the loop i get the expected results so there is no MySQL query issue. Im no Bash expert so im kind of lost here.

Comment: The process substitution should work. It's impossible to figure out what's going on since nobody can duplicate your `mysql` query. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Run the script with bash -x. This will allow youbto track your variables